# Raising ValueError in a class

Tags: python, class, valueerror

Let's try this again as my previous post wasn't that clear. I'm a newbie in Python and I'm working on a school project. However I'm stuck on a small part of code.

#Goal

Raise a ValueError when class is called with the wrong arguments.
Check argument age for float/int type and check if arguments is between 0 and 10.

Example:

```
class Dog():

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name                     

        def check_arg(age):
            if isinstance(age, (int,float)) and age >= 0 and age <= 10:
                 return age
            else:
                 raise ValueError

        self.age = check_arg(age)
```

Now to check if it works I first put

```
henry = Dog("Henry", 10)
print(henry.age)
```

The results is printed: 10

Now I check if it is not true and put:

```
henry = Dog("Henry", 11)
print(henry.age)
```

Now I get the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Folder\test.py", line 17, in 
henry = Dog("Henry", 11)

File "c:\Folder\test.py", line 12, in **init**
self.age = check_arg(age)

File "c:\Folder\test.py", line 10, in check_arg
raise ValueError

ValueError

So it does return a ValueError, but I think the function is handling it wrong. When I return instead of raise ValueError it shows: <class 'ValueError'>

Any tips?

Comment: You are trying to *Raise a ValueError when class is called with the wrong arguments*, and this is what happens. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: What makes you think it's "handling it wrong"?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? Well, usually you should raise an object like `raise ValueError()` but it is basically ok as it is.

Comment: `raise ValueError` actually creates an instance of the class to be raised as an exception. `return` is not a correct way to trigger an exception. What behaviour you expect to see?

Comment: *I think the function is handling it wrong* - there's no error handling in this code. That's why you see the error getting displayed instead.

Comment: Raising an exception is the *opposite* of returning a value. When the exception is raised, the function doesn't return *at all* if you don't catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I wish my teacher was as fast as you guys. But he said I could ignore the traceback bit. (spend hours trying to solve this)

```
raise ValueError()
```

was correct